# How to create builtin function mock used by object in tested function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to test a function from my Python application. The code looks like this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from mock import MagicMock
import configparser


def read_config_sections(filename):
    cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cp.read(filename)
    sections = list()

    for section in cp.sections():
        sections.append(section)
    return sections


class TestReadConfigSection(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("__main__.open", MagicMock(return_value="[SECTION1]"))
    def test_read_config_sections(self):
        sections = read_config_sections("somename.ini")
        self.assertEqual(["SECTION1"], sections)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

I want to mock the `open` function used by `ConfigParser` method to read the configuration. Can someone tell me how do it well? When I run the code above, the variable `sections` is an empty list.

Or maybe you have a better idea how to test this function.

Comment: Ok. Instead __main__.open I have to use builtins.open but when I di it there is exception AttributeError: __exit__

Answer (score 1):

```
import configparser
import io
from mock import patch, mock_open
import unittest


def read_config_sections(filename):
    cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cp.read(filename)
    sections = list()
    for section in cp.sections():
        sections.append(section)
    return sections


class TestReadConfigSection(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("builtins.open", return_value=io.StringIO("[SECTION1]"))
    def test_read_config_sections(self, mock_open):
        sections = read_config_sections("somename.ini")
        self.assertEqual(sections, ["SECTION1"])


if "__main__" == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

Solution found here: https://mapleoin.github.io/perma/mocking-python-file-open

Thanks for help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `__builtins__.open` rather than `__main__.open`

You could also use the [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) function instead.

Comment: When I use __builtins__.open there is an error

ImportError: No module named '__builtins__'